# Como mostrar PDF usando Viewer.js do servidor?

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc-5, pdf

Na página View, eu tenho o seguinte de código:

```
<iframe style="width:800px; height:550px;" id="FileReload" src="@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Account", new { id = Model.Id })" onerror="function_documenthide();"></iframe>
```

Cada navegador tem seu PDF diferente.

O problema é o navegador safari e IE. O Safari não mostra PDF e IE é muuuuuito pesado.

Estou tentando mostrando PDF padrão de todos navegadores usando [ViewerJS](http://viewerjs.org/).

Ela funciona no local de onde está o seu PDF.(AppData/Documento/teste.pdf).

Então coloquei esse código para trabalhar com ViewerJS:(Com servidor)

```
<iframe style="width:815px; height:550px;" id="FileReload" src="/ViewerJS/#../@Url.Action("GetPDF", "Account", new { id= Model.ID})"></iframe>
```

Mais não funciona, dá esse problema abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**UPDATE**

Com PDF local funciona:

```
<iframe style="float:right;" src="/ViewerJS/pdf-test.pdf" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

No Controller ele retorna com tipo application/pdf:

```
PDF = ((byte[])reader["File"]);
return new FileContentResult(PDF, "application/pdf");
```

Alguma idéia ?

Comment: Qual navegador? Qual erro ocorre?

Comment: Na verdade todos navegadores não mostram PDF usando ViewerJS, mais o google chrome mostra o erro.

Comment: Erro : The provided value 'moz-chunked-arraybuffer' is not a valid enum value of type XMLHttpRequestResponseType.

Comment: @Laerte o problema foi resolvido, veja a resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problema resolvido, segue código:

***Html:***

```
<iframe src="/Scripts/ViewerJS/#/home/getpdf" width='400' height='300' allowfullscreen webkitallowfullscreen></iframe>
```

***Controller:***

```
public ActionResult GetPDF()
{
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        var t = client.DownloadData("http://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/fw4.pdf");

        return new FileContentResult(t, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

*Veja o resultado:*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Muito bom! :) +1